# Python - how to do operations on individual items in list or string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i was wondering how in Python would you represent something like this:

take string - 'abcdefg'
add items in this string

'a' + 'b' = somevar

somevar + 'c' = someothervar

etc

Thanks

Comment: You should consider looking for basic python tutorials. There are plenty of tutorials that will teach you exactly what you're asking here.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I'm not sure what the OP is asking... I think the semi-pseudocode is somewhat misleading, and I would ask the OP to instead trying to express in an English sentence or two what they're trying to achieve with example inputs and outputs to clarify

Comment: I have the same feeling to be honest, either the question is basic or the question is wrongly asked. The title doesn't match with the pseudo code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just index the list/string. It's the same kind of syntax for both lists and strings.

```
>>> s = 'abcdefg'
>>> s[0] + s[1] # This does the operation 'a' + 'b'
'ab'
```

Lists and strings are both [sequence types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) in Python and sequences in Python are 0-indexed. This means the first item is at index 0, the second at index 1, etc.

Also note that when you want to store these values in a variable, the syntax in Python is not `'a' + 'b' = somevar`. Instead, it is `somevar = 'a' + 'b'`. The item(s) you want to assign to should always be on the left hand side of the assignment operator. So if I wanted to store the result above I would just do:

```
>>> somevar = s[0] + s[1]
```

Then you could print the value of `somevar` to see that it indeed holds the result you computed.

```
>>> somevar
'ab'
```

Comment: @user2818751 If my answer was helpful to you, feel free to accept it by clicking the green checkmark on the left-hand side.